# Create multiple Facebook messenger bots with one app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

The Facebook messenger bot API seems to require you create a Facebook app for each bot, for each page.  The Facebook app stores the webhook, and connects to the page.

Is there a way to have a single Facebook app for many bots connected to many pages?

If you create a bot to resell to clients as a service, you need to be able to do this. But there does not seem to be any way. You need to create a Facebook app for each client, and go through the Facebook app review process for each page which is very difficult.

How can this be avoided?
Can a single Facebook app have multiple webhooks, or access to multiple pages messages?

Comment: One app, one webhook URL. But of course your bot can subscribe to more than one page.

Comment: How does the bot know which page the question is coming from? How can you subscribe to a client's page through the Facebook API, and how do you get permission for their page?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not going to pick the documentation apart for you and present it in bite-sized chunks. A sample data structure can be found in there, and how to subscribe your app to pages is explained in the basic setup instructions, too.

Comment: I know how to subscribe an app to a page manually for my own pages. But how can a user subscribe their own page to the bot?

Comment: By logging in to your app and granting it the necessary permissions, so that your app can perform the necessary API call on their behalf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create one chatbot and can use this bot in multiple Facebook pages. All you need is to store `PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN` for each page and response messages to the user with right `PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN`. You should get the necessary permissions to get page access tokens by Facebook Login. And then you need to subscribe the page to your chatbot(app): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps

One important thing is Facebook generates a unique identifier for users for each page. Some user#A will have a different SENDER_ID/RECIPIENT_ID on different pages.

Comment: Wondering how this scales, and how receptive Facebook is to this? (they seem to want to review every bot?) Can you have a single Facebook app subscribed to thousands of pages?

Comment: One Facebook App(chatbot) can subscribe to any number of pages. Currently, there is no limit on the app side. But 'one Facebook page' can subscribe up to 10 apps.

Comment: But just one webhook configuration correct? I guess this will work, just need to modify our webhook as our webhook had a specific argument for a given integration. We could use the page id passed on every call to map it to the correct client's page.  I'll give this a shot.